# Using gbm to eliminate variables before glm

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, boosting

I have a classification problem I am attempting to model using logistic regression (via the `glm` package in R):

```
cols <- c("x", "z", "a", "b", "c") 
formula = paste0("x ~ ", paste(cols, collapse = "+"))
formula = as.formula(formula)
```

I have a bunch of explanatory variables at the moment. How advisable is it to model this relationship using `gbm`, see the relative inference strength of each variable, and then remove seemingly meaningless variables before `glm` regression?

I ask just because I have done this in the past, with `glm` and `gbm` giving seemingly contradictory signals on different explanatory variables.